# Pulling Text from Type 'Navigable String' and 'Tag' on Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm stuck on parsing part of Rotten Tomatoes website that has the critics score as a tag and the "%" separately. I followed some SO suggestions such as using `find_all('span',text="true")`, but Python 3.5.1 shell returned this error: `AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'find_all'` I also tried finding the direct child of Beautiful Soup object `critiscore`, but received the same error. Please tell me where I went wrong. Here's my python code:

```
def get_rating(address):
    """pull ratings numbers from rotten tomatoes"""
    RTaddress = urllib.request.urlopen(address)
    tomatoe = BeautifulSoup(RTaddress, "lxml")
    for criticscore in tomatoe.find('span', class_=['meter-value superPageFontColor']):
        print(''.join(criticscore.find_all('span', recursive=False))) #print the Tomatometer
```

Also, here's the code on Rotten Tomatoes I'm interested in scraping:

```
<div class="critic-score meter">
                        <a href="#contentReviews" class="unstyled articleLink" id="tomato_meter_link">
                            <span class="meter-tomato icon big medium-xs certified_fresh pull-left"></span>
                            <span class="meter-value superPageFontColor"><span>96</span>%</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem line is this one:

```
for criticscore in tomatoe.find('span', class_=['meter-value superPageFontColor']):
```

Here, you are locating a single element via `find()` and then iterate over its children which can be the text nodes as well as other elements (when you iterate over an element, this is what happens in `BeautifulSoup`).

Instead, you probably meant to use `find_all()` instead of `find()`:

```
for criticscore in tomatoe.find_all('span', class_=['meter-value superPageFontColor']):
```

Or, you can use a single [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) instead:

```
for criticscore in tomatoe.select('span.meter-value > span'):
    print(criticscore.get_text())
```

where `>` means a direct parent-child relationship (this is your `recursive=False` replacement).

Comment: at first i did use find_all, but python printed out another rating with the same class that I did not need. Is there a way to only print the first rating using find_all() or use find() to print rating and percentage sign?

Comment: thanks, i used your css selector and printed first element in the list